# Change Desktop folder path

Tags: directory, system

This is my first question here, I'm trying to create a little script, that change icons shown in Desktop. I mean, when I Click on a button, I  would launch this simple script

```
cp $HOME/.config/Desktop5/user-dirs.dirs $HOME/.config
```

in Desktop5/user.dirs i wrote:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

I wrote 5 script for each most used folder: Downloads, Pictures, Music, Desktop and Videos

It works, but unfortunately, sometimes the desktop doesn't refresh soon and I have to click several time the same button before than see desktop icons, change.

How can I resolve this problem?

Edit:

I thanks for the answer, i substituded

```
`cp $HOME/.config/Desktop5/user-dirs.dirs $HOME/.config`
```

with this two command:
`rm -r ~/Desktop`
`ln -s ~/Downloads ~/Desktop`

I Couldn't use
`rm -r-i ~/Desktop`

because this command was launched by a script
now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a script for that, remove the actual `~/Desktop` folder (if it is empty), and create a link to `~/Downloads` in its place:

```
rm -r -i ~/Desktop
ln -s ~/Downloads ~/Desktop
```